# Proof by induction on $m$: when $V \subseteq R^n$, then $\forall v_1,\dots,v_m \in V. \text{span}(v_1,\dots,v_m) \subseteq V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I want to proof by induction, that when $V \subseteq R^n$, then $\forall v_1,\dots,v_m \in V. \text{span}(v_1,\dots,v_m) \subseteq V$. I think I got the base cases right, but I am struggling to figure out how the inductive step needs to look, or how induction helps in the proof at all. I think you could do the same proof I did in the base case 2 for a subset of 1 vector, for a subset of any number of vectors in a proof mostly analogous to the one I wrote.

Here are my base cases:

[image]

Can you give me an idea for the outline of the induction and why induction is even useful (or necessary?) here?

Comment: The title of the question seems to be unrelated to the question in the body. To show that $\mathrm{span}\,\{v_1, \ldots, v_m\} \subseteq V$, just use that $V$ is closed under finite linear combinations of its elements. Perhaps you could show that by induction, if its not clear.

Comment: I'm sorry, why does the title say something different from the proposition to prove?

Comment: That is what I did in base case for $m = 1$ and what I said could be done for an unspecified $m$ and why I don't understand why and how to use induction here.

Comment: I agree with the first comment. There is nothing really to do by induction; you need only use the definitions of subspace and span.

Comment: @JohnBrevik That is my point though, as I also wrote in my question: I don't see how to use induction here. But I am required to.

Comment: Oh, OK, I see. Well, you could run a similar argument to the one you just did taking $v\in \mathop{Span} \{v_1, \dots, v_m\}, w\in \mathop{Span} \{v_{m+1}\}$.

Comment: Neither the title nor the text of the question assumes that $V$ is a linear subspace (as opposed to merely a subset) of $\mathbb R^n$. Without that assumption, the result is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that a vector space $V$ is (by definition) closed under addition and multiplication by scalar. Let's prove by induction that it is also closed under all finite linear combinations.

Base case for $n=1$:

Take $x \in V$ and a scalar $\lambda$. We have $\lambda x \in V$ since $V$ is closed under multiplication by scalar.

Base case for $n=2$:

Take $x, y \in V$ and two scalars $\lambda$ and $\mu$. We wish to prove that $\lambda x + \mu y \in V$.

Using the previous base case, $\lambda x \in V$ and $\mu y \in V$, so $\lambda x + \mu y \in V$, since $V$ is closed under addition.

Assume that $V$ is closed under all linear combinations of $n$ vectors, for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let's prove that this implies that its also closed under linear combinations of $n+1$ vectors.

Take $v_1, \ldots, v_n \in V$ and scalars $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$. We wish to prove that $\lambda_1v_1 + \ldots + \lambda_nv_n + \lambda_{n+1}v_{n+1} \in V$.

By inductive assumption, $\lambda_1v_1 + \ldots + \lambda_nv_n \in V$, and by the base case for $n=1$, we have $\lambda_{n+1}v_{n+1} \in V$. By the base case for $n=2$, we conclude:

$$V \ni  (\lambda_1v_1 + \ldots + \lambda_nv_n) + \lambda_{n+1}v_{n+1} = \lambda_1v_1 + \ldots + \lambda_nv_n + \lambda_{n+1}v_{n+1}$$

This completes the proof.

---

Now, we need to prove that for $v_1, \ldots, v_m \in V$ we have  $\mathrm{span}\{v_1, \ldots, v_m\} \subseteq V$.

Take $x \in \mathrm{span}\{v_1, \ldots, v_m\}$. By definition of $\mathrm{span}$, there exist scalars $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_m$ such that $$x = \lambda_1v_1 + \ldots + \lambda_mv_m$$

We see that $x$ is a finite linear combination of elements of $V$, hence $x \in V$.

We conclude that $\mathrm{span}\{v_1, \ldots, v_m\} \subseteq V$.